# Using Google Drive to host thousands of photos for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments, data-storage

I am wondering about using Google Drive for 3000+ photo attachments in ArcGIS Online (AGOL) pop ups.

I have an asset inventory with about 1250 records. Each record has three photos that are currently stored on a work server and the path to these photos is just in a text field (so to view a photo, you must copy and paste path into Windows viewer...).

I have been cleaning up this database in ArcGIS Pro, and need to upload it to ArcGIS Online. The end users of this database will only have access to AGOL. My org will not host these photos on AGOL because of credits, but using Google Drive/ Photos(?) was brought up as a potential solution. I can see it's possible to use Google Drive photos with the URL containing the image id.

The goal would be to see the thumbnail in the pop up of at least the first photo.  With the amount of records/ photos, I guess I'm wondering if there a workflow that:

1. brings photos from multiple local folders into Google Drive with the same name
2. a way around manually copying and pasting every single image URL into AGOL
3. asset data will be added to or updated using Survey123.

Would using a related Attachment table be a better solution?

I am worried about the users of this not being GIS users.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? A related attachment table would still host the photos in AGOL, which you said you don't want to do.

Comment: You could use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api?hl=en_GB) to automate the uploading of your photos? Don't know how you would access drive from AGOL though, never done it.